# How to differentiate selected suggestion and normal text from spyglass library android?

Tags: android, token, linkedin-api, multiautocompletetextview

I am using this library https://github.com/linkedin/Spyglass for showing social tag like facebook and linkedin.
But after selection how to differentiate selected suggestion and other typed normal string?

If user type "Hello @A" in EditText, here @A is selected from suggestion.
So during getText() how we know @A is selected from suggestion?

I want to convert this text into formate like "Hello {{@key#userid#A#}}"

Comment: https://github.com/linkedin/Spyglass/issues/28 here we have some similar solution. but it is not perfect. we can't replace like this way becase we lost index after.